# Proving the image of a projection is a manifold by using the quotient manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, quotient-spaces

**Edit: Below, spurred by Jack Lee's comment, I am going to change the notation to more accurately reflect my question. I believe this can be done without creating a new question.**

Let $M \subset R^{n+k}, \; n > 2,\;k > 1$ be a smooth, embedded submanifold of dimension $n-1$ and let $\rho : M \rightarrow R^k$ be the orthogonal projection onto the last $k$ coordinates. Further, suppose the map $\phi : R^l \times M \rightarrow M := \phi(t,x) = x + t$,  maps each fiber $\rho^{-1}(y_1,\ldots,y_k)$ into itself (here $l < n$ and I am identifying $R^l$ with the subset of $R^{n+k}$ consisting of all vectors with last $n+k-l$ coordinates all equal to zero). In other words, $R^l$ together with $M$ satisfy the hypothesis of the Quotient Manifold Theorem (as presented in Lee, *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, Theorem 21.10). **I would like to prove that $\rho(M)$ is a submanifold of $R^k$** (embedded, preferably, but even immersed will do).

**Edit, an added assumption**: I also know that $\rho$ is of constant rank $r < k$.

**Edit, another property of $M$**: I know that if two points of $M$ belong to the same "leaf" (with respect to the action) then their corresponding tangent spaces are exactly the same. That is, the tangent space of a point of $M$ depends *only* on the last $k$ coordinates.

**Edit**: In my mind, I see this as an undulating sheet of paper (Letter or A4, depending on where you live) standing on edge on a table top, and the projection being the "curve" where the paper meets the table. The fibers are just lines perpendicular to the table with $l = 1$ and the action just translation by a real number. I understand $n,l,k$ are not quite right (here $n=3,k=2$ but only $l = 1$), but that is the picture that made me think the projection might be a manifold.

From the cited Theorem I know there exists a smooth structure on $M\:/\:R^l$ such that the  quotient map $\pi: M \rightarrow M\: /\: R^l$ is a smooth submersion. I also know (Theorem 4.30, also from Lee) there is a unique (should be injective) smooth map $\tilde{F} : M \: / \:R^l \rightarrow R^k$ such that $\rho = \tilde{F} \circ \pi$. **I have two questions**: First, am I correct in saying, because of the topologies involved and the fact that projections are open maps, that $\tilde{F}$ is a topological embedding onto its image ($\rho(M))$? Second, if the answer to the first question is no, can anyone give me a hint as to where I've gone wrong? If the answer to the first question is yes, is it then true that in order to conclude $\rho(M)$ is a submanifold (embedded) of $R^k$ I need to prove that $\tilde{F}$ is an immersion? I believe that with my added assumption on the rank of $\rho$ that this last is "obvious" and that $\rho(M)$ is indeed an embedded submanifold of $R^k$ of dimension $r$, but I am wary of my thought processes.

Thank you in advance for any comments and information.

Comment: What does $x+u$ mean if $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $u\in \mathbb R^k$?

Comment: @Jack Lee: Apologies, I am identifying $R^k$ with the $k$-dimensional subspace of $R^n$ consisting of vectors with the last $n-k$ coordinates all equal to zero. However, I feel I also need to "recast" the notation to make my intent clearer and to add an assumption I neglected initially (I think I can do that without having to create a new question). Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This really is more of a comment, but it's a bit too long.

The setup still doesn't quite make sense. First of all, in order for the map $\phi$ to take its values in $M$, you need to assume that $M$ is invariant under all translations in the $(x^1,\dots,x^l)$ coordinates, and from that assumption it follows that $M$ is just a product manifold $\mathbb R^l\times M_0$, where
$$
M_0 = \{ z\in \mathbb R^{n+k-l}: (0,z)\in M\}.
$$
Moreover, the assumption that $\phi$ maps each fiber $\rho^{-1}(y_1,\dots,y_k)$ into itself is superfluous, because each map $x \mapsto \phi(t,x)$ doesn't change the last $k$ coordinates at all.

In any case, there's no reason why $\rho(M)$ should be a submanifold. Here's a counterexample.

Let $n=3$, $k=2$, and $l=2$, and let $M$ be the image of the following embedding $\alpha\colon \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^5$:
\begin{equation*}
\alpha(u,v,w) = (u,v,w,\sin 2w, \sin w).
\end{equation*}
Then $M$ is an embedded $3$-manifold, invariant under translations in the first two variables. But the projection onto $\mathbb R^2$ is the lemniscate traced out by the curve $\gamma(t) = (\sin 2t, \sin t)$, which is not a manifold. (See my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, Example 4.19.)

Comment: Thanks for this, I will study your comment. In particular, I don't immediately see why $M_0$ is a manifold, in my mind it's almost as if that's what I'm trying to prove (i.e. the projection of $M$ on the second factor is a manifold). However, I'm sure you're right, I just need to think about it. I have added a couple of comments to the question which may clarify my thinking. I know this is getting messy so you may choose not to respond, just want to thank you for your comments thus far and for being quite civil.

Comment: Hint: to show that $M_0$ is a manifold, show that the map $F\colon M\to \mathbb R^l$ given by $F(x^1,\dots,x^l,x^{l+1},\dots,x^{n+k}) = (x^1,\dots,x^l)$ is a submersion. This follows easily from the fact that the vector fields $\partial/\partial x^1,\dots,\partial/\partial x^l$ are all tangent to $M$.

Comment: -Thanks for the kind hint. I'll work on that, plus I'm still verifying that I've conveyed my question (it's actually a real-world problem) correctly.